# is it possible to use "attribute value templates" in variable or param?

Tags: xslt

this is nice and short:

```xml
<img src="{$base}/{@filename}.jpg" />
```

but sometimes you need to reuse the `src`, so it turns into this:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="imgsrc">
    <xsl:value-of select="$base">/<xsl:value-of select="@filename">
    <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<img src="$imgsrc" />
```

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template you can't use the "curly brackets interpolation syntax" outside of literal element attributes, but there might be a not-so-hacky hack to do the trick? I'm lazy, I know.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, there are a few other places besides literal result element attributes that support AVTs, most notably the `name` attribute of `<xsl:element>` which allows you to output elements with a dynamically-generated name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `select` expression to define the variable, using the `concat` function to join the various bits together:

```
<xsl:variable name="imgsrc" select="concat($base, '/', @filename, '.jpg')"/>
<img src="{$imgsrc}" />
```

This is also more efficient than the `<xsl:value-of>` approach because by using `select` you're setting the variable to a string value directly rather than creating a tree fragment containing a text node which then has to be converted back into a string when you reference the variable.

Comment: perfect! and so non-hacky - quite the opposite!

Answer (score 6):

XSLT 3.0 contains some goodies in this area:

(a) a concat operator

```
select="$base || '/' || @filename || '.jpg'
```

(b) "text value templates"

```
<xsl:variable name="x">{$base}/{@filename}/.jpg</xsl:variable>
```

(which needs to be enabled, for compatibility reasons)

Comment: Text value templates: very nice! I've been wishing for a way to do ATV's in non-attributes, especially in text.